# OSX 14: identify mojave microphone missing permission

Tags: audiounit, macos-mojave

I wonder,
I developed my own voice recording app for mac.
In Mojave, user must give microphone permissions.

How can I identify if the user gave me those permissions?
I noticed that I can still Init and start the AudioUnit, even without permissions.
Any idea?